# create next month and previous month link menu link in calendar module in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, calendar

how to create next month and previous month link menu link in calendar module in drupal 7

### Previous Month <<                                      >> Next Month

```
                   calendar display area!!
```

Answer (score 0):

When you edit that view go to "Pager section" and select pager type. Then in pager settings you can choose where your pager should be placed : top / bottom / both.